# vectorize a constant function in octave

Tags: matlab, octave

I am having this existential trouble trying to define a constant funcion that takes a vector as an argument:

I want to define a function like:

```
>f=@(x) 0.0;           % a constant function (zero or any other constant value).
>xx=linspace(0,10,10); % ten values where I want to evaluate the function
```

and when I run it, I get:

```
>> f(xx)
ans = 0
```

And I really was expecting a vector of zeros. (I dont see how to incorporate the vectorization feature into a constant function)

Does anyone have the soluction for this simple issue?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: _I really was expecting a vector of zeros_ `f=@(x) 0.0` defines a function that simply outputs `0`. Is `f = @(x) zeros(size(x))` what you want?

Comment: Or `@(x)x*0` would work also. If you don’t use `x` in your function, then it output is independent of its input. Did you expect the function to be called for each element of the input in turn? Octave doesn’t work this way.

Comment: Ok, @LuisMendo in that cse, it will only work for a zero-valued constant function, but not for, say, f=@(x) 3.0, rigth?. I would expect an output of 3... I think it could be set as: f=@(x) a*ones(1,size(x));

Comment: @CrisLuengo @(x)x*0 will also not work for another constant that 0. "Did you expect the function to be called for each element of the input in turn? ". I think this is what I want!.

Comment: So, maybe `f = @(x) repmat(a,size(x))` is what you're after. I don't really get what you want, sorry

Comment: @LuisMendo Ok. So, imagine a function like ```f=@(x) x.^2```, it can take a number "x" as an argument and also can take a vector. If you input a vector "x" it will perform an element-wise operation an return a vector with all the values of "x.*x". It works this way because I inserted the "dot" before the operation "^". So, I converted a function into something that can take a vector as an argument. How can I program a constant function to perform the same?. Say, f(x) =a ???

Comment: Isn’t that what my previous suggestion (`repmat`) does?

Comment: @LuisMendo Indeed!. It is!. Thanks for that!. I was only adressing my problem, so it can be more understandable. On the other side, its a pity that octave does not have the possibility to solve this in a more elegant way. In julia, for example, I know that a function can be defined as f (x) = 0.0; and then f. (vect) = 0,0,0, .. will return a vector of 0s.

Comment: Great! I posted it as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To repeat a constant `a` as dictated by the input shape, you can use

```
f = @(x) repmat(a, size(x));
```

Example:

```
>> a = 5;
>> f = @(x) repmat(a,size(x));
>> f([10 20 30; 40 50 60])
ans =
     5     5     5
     5     5     5
```

Answer (score 1):

ok, so from the comments above you want a function that will return an array the same size as the input, but with all values equal to some predefined constant.

@Luis's method above will work. I'm not sure about Matlab these days, but in older versions at least and in Octave repmat isn't the fastest, and there are other, lower overhead ways of generating repeated arrays. If it's a function that may get called a lot, I prefer to use  `ones()` array expansion. (It also combines with broadcasting well, not that that's necessary in this case).

E.g.:

```
>> f = @(x)  repmat(5,size(x));

>> f([10 20 30; 40 50 60])
ans =
     5     5     5
     5     5     5

>> g = @(x) 5*ones(size(x));

>> g([10 20 30; 40 50 60])
ans =
     5     5     5
     5     5     5
```

doing a quick and dirty loop to estimate time requirement, we see that in Octave 5.2.0 the repmat version takes about 5x longer for the same operations:

```
>> tic;for idx = 1:1e4, f(rand(4,2,3));endfor,toc
Elapsed time is 1.54 seconds.

>> tic;for idx = 1:1e5, f(rand(4,2,3));endfor,toc
Elapsed time is 17.6487 seconds.

>> tic;for idx = 1:1e4, g(rand(4,2,3));endfor,toc
Elapsed time is 0.337171 seconds.

>> tic;for idx = 1:1e5, g(rand(4,2,3));endfor,toc
Elapsed time is 3.06284 seconds.
```

FYI this is something I picked up from [Pascal Getreuer's "Writing Fast MATLAB Code"](https://www.ee.columbia.edu/%7Emarios/matlab/Writing_Fast_MATLAB_Code.pdf) which i strongly recommend if working in Octave, as it currently doesn't have many of the code speedups that Matlab has implemented in recent years.

Comment: Good point. In Matlab R201b they seem to be equally fast